# cors error preflight alow origin mismatch for apollo client and sever

Tags: authentication, cors, apollo-client, apollo-server

### Overview

I am trying to get authentications set up in Apollo but I keep running into this network error: CORS error PreflightAllowOriginMismatch. I have looked and tried so many solutions on the internet but nothing is working.
I have my client running on localhost:3000 and my server on localhost:4000.

### Code

```
//client index.js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
import App from './App';
import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
  credentials: 'include',
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

render((
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>
  ), document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```
//server index.js
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const schema = require('./schema');
const models = require('./sequelize/models');

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: req => ({
    ...req,
    models,
  })
});

const app = express();
var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  credentials: true // <-- REQUIRED backend setting
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
server.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: false });
app.listen({ port: 4000 });
```

I'm honestly lost at this point. I new to apollo and for the life of me cannot find what i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am unsure about the security the following changes fixed my issue.

remove

```
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  credentials: true // <-- REQUIRED backend setting
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

update
`server.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: {credentials: true, origin: true} });`

the final file:

```
//server index.js
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
const express = require('express');
const schema = require('./schema');
const models = require('./sequelize/models');

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: req => ({
    ...req,
    models,
  })
});

const app = express();
server.applyMiddleware({
  app,
  cors: {credentials: true, origin: true}
});
app.listen({ port: 4000 });
```